# weird signal received

Tags: c, linux, signals

I set up signal filter on my application as described [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_sigmask), except I block all the signals.

```
sigfillset (&signalSet);
```

And I receive weird signal #36 which is not described in public documentation nor in /usr/include/bits/signum.h. 
But, it looks like this signal affects sem_wait() in the main thread, and is not being blocked. I catch such an exception:

> ::sem_wait() failed, code: 4(Interrupted system call)

Red Hat 4.1.2-44 (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704) is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a POSIX realtime signal. These are in the range of SIGRTMIN+1 to SIGRTMAX (which you should find in /usr/include/bits/signum.h).

See man 7 signals, Section 'Real-time Signals' for detailed information.

If you block all signals with

`sigfillset(&signalset);
  sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&signalset,NULL);`

or

`sigfillset(&signalset);
  pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK,&signalset,NULL);`

and still get signal 36, I guess you use library functions that are using signals as well.

You could use 'strace' to see if and when signal functions are called.